# Echo shortcode in WordPress AJAX function return

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have searched all over here and the web but cant seem to get this to work - hopefully you all can help.

I am trying to setup product filters for WooCommerce on the category page (like filter products depending on color etc)

I have the ajax working but I have a shortcode that I want to display for each product and this doesnt work - any ideas how to get it to show?

Code below:

PHP

```
function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {
  // Enqueue script
wp_register_script('afp_script', plugins_url() . '/plugin-name/js/product-filter-ajax.js', false, null, false);
  wp_enqueue_script('afp_script');
  wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
        'afp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'afp_nonce' ), // Create nonce which we later will use to verify AJAX request
        'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      )
  );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);
```

JS

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $(".loading").hide();

var taxonomy = [];
var terms = [];

         $('.filter-option input').click( function(event) {

                 var taxonomy_idx = $.inArray($(this).closest(".filter-title-wrapper").attr('data-attribute'), taxonomy);
                 if (taxonomy_idx == -1) {
             taxonomy.push($(this).closest(".filter-title-wrapper").attr('data-attribute'));
             } else {
         taxonomy.splice(taxonomy_idx, 1);
            }

            var terms_idx = $.inArray($(this).val(), terms);
            if (terms_idx == -1) {
            terms.push($(this).val());
        } else {
        terms.splice(terms_idx, 1);
     }



            // Prevent default action - opening tag page
            if (event.preventDefault) {
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                event.returnValue = false;
            }

            // Get tag slug from title attirbute
                    var selecetd_taxonomy = taxonomy.toString();;


                    var selected_term = terms.toString();
                    var selected_term_speach = '\'' + selected_term.split(',').join('\',\'') + '\'';
                    console.log(selecetd_taxonomy);
                    console.log(selected_term_speach);

            // After user click on tag, fade out list of posts
            $('.products').fadeOut();
                    $(".loading").fadeIn();

            data = {
                action: 'filter_posts', // function to execute
                afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce, // wp_nonce
                taxonomy: selecetd_taxonomy, // selected tag
                            term: selected_term_speach,
                };

            $.post( afp_vars.afp_ajax_url, data, function(response) {
                        $(".loading").fadeOut();
                if( response ) {
                    // Display posts on page
                    $('.products').html( response );
                    // Restore div visibility
                    $('.products').fadeIn();

                };
            });
        });
    });
```

PHP TO GET POSTS

```
// Script for getting posts
function ajax_filter_get_posts( $taxonomy, $term ) {
ob_start();
global  $woocommerce, $product;

  // Verify nonce
  if( !isset( $_POST['afp_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce' ) )
    die('Permission denied');

  $taxonomy = $_POST['taxonomy'];
  $term = $_POST['term'];

  $term = str_replace("\\", '', $term);

  // WP Query
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
      );

  if ($term == "''") {
}
  else {
    $args = array(
      'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
          'terms' => array($term),
          'field' => 'slug',
          'operator' => 'IN'
      ),
  )
      );
  }

?>
<h1> <?php echo $term ?> </h1>
<?php
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<li <?php wc_product_class(); ?>>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_shortcode]'); ?>
</li>


<?php

 ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    <h2>No posts found</h2>
  <?php endif;

  die();
  return ob_get_clean();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
```

Excuse the messyness of the code, just trying to get it to work before I can start to neaten it up. Any advice on how to approach this in a better way please let me know.

Thanks and appreciate the help!

UPDATE-----

Tried to add the shortcode callback, but this doesnt work or I have the wrong code

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
  ps_register_shortcode_ajax( 'ajax_filter_get_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts' ); 
} );

function ps_register_shortcode_ajax( $callable, $action ) {

  if ( empty( $_POST['action'] ) || $_POST['action'] != $action )
    return;

  call_user_func( $callable );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Ajax calls don't have the access to whole WordPress environment and that's why your shortcode not working. Instead of calling the shortcode directly, call its callback. Refer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - what you say makes sense now, but not sure how to call its callback - I tried to add the code (see in my question under UPDATE - will be easier to read than in the comment) - is this what you mean?

Comment: Can you able to share your shortcode function `[product_shortcode]` here?

Comment: I am using the Divi Theme and it outputs one of its "layouts": ---
function product_shortcode($moduleid) {
        return do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="79"][/et_pb_section]');
}
add_shortcode('showmodule', 'product_shortcode');

Comment: I am too not sure about this Divi shortcode, can you just try replacing `<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_shortcode]'); ?>` with `<?php echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="79"][/et_pb_section]'); ?>` in your function?

Comment: So I did a test shortcode that just echo'ed a string and this worked. So it must be an issue with the shortcode. :( not sure how to solve this!

Comment: I need to check the overall code for a solution. Would you mind providing WordPress admin panel credentials via https://www.outsource-wordpress.com/contact-us/? I'l then post the solution here.